# event receiver alternative for office 365

Tags: office-365, csom

I'm trying to add some post-input logic into a couple of custom lists, which I would typically do through an event receiver.

- field a (user input)
- field b (user input)
- field c (hidden) = field a + field b + additional logic

I cannot make field c a calculated column and looking at remote event receivers seems like overkill.

Is there any other approach that can solve an isolated problem, maybe using [PreSaveAction](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pre-save-action-on-document-libraries-in-sharepoint-2013-and/)?

Comment: Would a workflow not work?

Comment: PreSaveAction, workflow, PowerApp/Flow, PowerShell script, console applications, remote event receivers, all capable of doing what you want.

Comment: presaveaction and remote event receivers are completely different approaches. I'm looking for a lightweight solution, but if the changes are made in quick view I dont think I can handle it through presave